# Finding probability of unsafe lift simulation

Tags: python, numpy

[image]

I can find this using Excel but I'd like to know how to do it using Python.

1. Each column under Person is randomly generated with normal distribution of a standard deviation 15 and mean of 80.
2. Number of people is randomly generated between 1 to 6.
3. Total weight is the sum of person with the number of people. e.g. the first one is the sum of first 4 person.
4. Unsafe is a boolean. If the total weight is more than 500 then 1 otherwise 0.
5. Trials is 3997. The sum of unsafe is 148. Then the probability is calculated by number over weight divided by trials.

I can create a normal distribution using numpy. I create a random number with 80 mean and 15 sd and a random number between 0 and 7 (1 to 6).

```
import numpy as np
from decimal import *
total_num = 0
i=1
trial = 100
while i < trial:
    rand_num =np.random.randint(1,7)
    person = np.random.normal(80, 15)
    total_weight = int(rand_num)*Decimal(person)
    # print(total_weight)
    if total_weight > int(500):
        total_num += total_num
    i += 1;
total_num/trial
```

But I am getting 0 in my output.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `total_num` is initialized to zero, and the only way it's ever modified is to add it to itself, so of course it is always zero.

Comment: Thanks. I just need to change to total_num += 1

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to modify `total_num += 1`.

```
import numpy as np

count = 0
i=int(1)
trial = int(10000)
limit = int(500)
while i < trial:
    rand_num =np.random.randint(1,7)
    person = np.random.normal(80, 15)
    total_weight = int(rand_num)*person
    # print(total_weight)
    if total_weight > limit:
        #print('yes')
        count += 1
        count
    i += 1;
print("Probability is: ")
print(count/trial)
```